# Unable to connect to MSSQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

While I try to make a connection to `MSSQL Server` using the following code:

```
try {
$c_info = array("Database" => "ddb", "UID" => "sa", "PWD" => "admin123");
echo var_dump(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL));

$db = sqlsrv_connect('LENOVOWIH\SQLEXPRESS', $c_info); // Make a connection to MSSQL
if($db) echo '\ntrue';
else echo "\nfalse : " . var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
}  catch(Exception $e) {
      echo $e . " " . sqlsrv_errors();
   }
```

`var_dump(sqlsrv_errors())` gives out :

```
    array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
      'SQLSTATE' => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
      1 => int -49
      'code' => int -49
      2 => string 'This extension requires the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712' (length=184)
      'message' => string 'This extension requires the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712' (length=184)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'IM002' (length=5)
      'SQLSTATE' => string 'IM002' (length=5)
      1 => int 0
      'code' => int 0
      2 => string '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified' (length=91)
      'message' => string '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified' (length=91)
```

I have already placed `extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` in my `php.ini` *(\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini)* file and `dll` inside the `ext` directory. I am using wampp with php version `5.5.12`

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you connect from other client? Maybe you need install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Comment: @Mate I am able to connect to `MySQL`

Comment: @Mate I installed ODBC driver and it worked. Could you please brief me in the answer, as what exactly was missing and what is the purpose of ODBC driver.

Comment: @Mate I was able to connect to DB from studio but missed from php code. After installing the driver, it worked but could you explain what exactly changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [ODBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434).
The sqlsrv driver is built on ODBC, which is actively maintained by Microsoft and provides access to features in the latest releases of SQL Server.

[image]